# Comma separated values in to multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table where it contains data in below format
[image]

How to achieve this in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Which version of **`MS SQL Server`** are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293157/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-columns-to-multiple-rows-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting Comma separated values in columns to multiple rows in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293157/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-columns-to-multiple-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: What were wrong with the (probably 100's) of other questions with answers that were presented to you when you searched and wrote this question?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is a different question with multiple columns with multiple values, using a bad data model

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes it is a duplicate, the OP just needs to apply some thinking to make it specific to their situation.

Comment: @DavidG for this you will need xmlsplit or a homebuild split function that returns the number of the value as well, for the other question you can simply use string_split

Comment: @t-clausen.dk What? There is no xmlsplit? Also, no you just use normal string split, do it twice and join the rows together with a DISTINCT.

Comment: @DavidG [XML split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771283/how-to-write-sql-query-for-this-result/29771520#29771520) and your solution is not possible, it return 1+4+9 rows instead of the expected 1+2+3 rows. Check the answer from Larmu to comprehend this better

Comment: @Wanderer, I am using Azure SQL Server, compatibility_level is 130, but cant use string split function.

Comment: @RamBhaskar do you mean the built in one, or the one in my answer?

Comment: @Larnu, I have not tried with DelimitedSplit8K, Let me check that.

Comment: I've also added a `OPENJSON` solution for you (should you have more than 8000 characters in a single delimited list), however, you should still be fixing your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [`DelimitedSplit8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), as information on the ordinal position is required (something `STRING_SPLIT` and many other splitters don't supply). The below is Pseudo SQL as well, as the OP has provided images, rather that textual data:

```
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(YT.Qualification,',') DSq
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(YT.Instituion,',') DSi
WHERE DSq.ItemNumber = DSi.ItemNumber;
```

The true answer here, as has been mentioned in the comments, however, is to fix the data model.

An alternative method would be to use `OPENJSON`. This is something I have only been introduced to recently, and I don't have access to a SQL Server 2016 instance to test this against (I have used SQL Fiddle to test it runs though, but not against the image provided for my same reason above). I beleive this should also achieve your goal though:

```
SELECT OJq.[value], OJi.[Value]
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT ca.[Key], ca.[value]
                  FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(YT.Qualification,',','","') + '"]') ca) OJq
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT ca.[Key], ca.[value]
                  FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(YT.Instituion,',','","') + '"]') ca) OJi
WHERE OJq.[Key] = OJi.[Key];
```

Comment: I want to replace comma with semi colon. I have replaced comma with semi colon, but  it throws error.:JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ';' is found at position 42."Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: @RamBhaskar what do you mean?  There are no commas in the final dataset. Do you mean on your original data it is now separated by a `;` instead of a `,`?

Comment: Yes, Now delimiter is semicolon; I used the query that you had given but in the same statement, I replaced comma with semi colon using replace function.

Comment: @RamBhaskar If the delimiter is now a `;` then just change the `REPLACE` from a `,` to `;`. An important part of using the SQL you get from the volunteers here is understanding it; if you don't you shouldn't be using it. Changing the delimiter is the simplest thing you can do here.